# how to get summary dataframe of classification metrics_report from several batches

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have two batches and I calculate classification metrics using [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) from each batch. I want to get the weighted summary out of both batches, in a way that it consider the `support` (number of samples from the class in that batch)

```
df_batch_1 = 
           class  precision  recall  f1-score  support
0              0       0.75    1.00      0.87     20.0
1              1       0.50    0.80      0.65     50.0
2              2       1.00    1.00      1.00    232.0
3              3       1.00    1.00      1.00     27.0

df_batch_2 = 
           class  precision  recall  f1-score  support
0              0       0.95    0.05      0.50     40.0
1              1       0.40    0.80      0.60     30.0
2              2       0.30    1.00      0.65    100.0
3              3       0.90    0.90      0.90     50.0
```

the summary of the `precision` for class0 should be

```
df_summary.loc['0'].prcision = (0.75*20 + 0.95*40)/(20 + 40)
```

I appreciate any comment on how I can get the dataframe summary of classification from all batches.